# how to resolve the reported error "runtime error exitcode 6" in C code?

Tags: c++

i have my code test on an OJ system for several times, and the results keep reporting the error "runtime error exitcode 6" on the specific 3rd and 4th run, one test contains 10 runs. except for these two failed run, others are all correct.

i checked online that "runtime error exitcode 6" means "Invalid file handle", but i don't even have a file variable or any process refered to FILE.

i tried to remove unnessary header files, only left two header files: 
`#include <stdio.h> #include<string>`
but it didn't work.
so maybe some of you can help me out of here. thanks a lot ... and i use C.

here is my code

```
    scanf("%d\n",&n); 

    int *A = new int[n];

    for(i = 1; i<n+1; i++) {
        scanf( "%d ",&A[i]); 
    }
    scanf( "\n");
```

Comment: You need to post your code if you expect us to help. We are good, but not mindreaders.. (also `#include<string>` should be `#include<string.h>`)

Comment: Please post your code!! However, `SIGABRT` is signal number 6.. and you should use `#include <string.h>`. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: i posted my code and changed the header file to string.h. the OJ system uses gcc compiler.

Comment: Uhh, `new[]` operator in __C__ code?

Comment: @timrau oh..my mistake, i always got confused between C and C++

Comment: Do not destroy your question after you have an answer.

Comment: I wasn't supposed to post all code, so i'll leave the key lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *A = new int[n];

for(i = 1; i<n+1; i++) {
    scanf( "%d ",&A[i]); 
}
```

`A`'s legal index range is [0, n-1] instead of [1, n]. Thus the last `scanf()` of this loop writes out of array boundary.

Comment: i considered that, but for other eight runs , it went well...well, i'll try to mordify as you suggest

Comment: great, i stretch the size of array to n+1, it works now. thanks.